# Как по нажатию запустить скрипт?

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate, java-ee, jsf

Всем привет ребята.Пишу приложение на `web-e`.Это сфера для меня новая и сложная,я перешел из андроида .Разобрал поврехностно темы  `Jsf(primefaces),Hibernate,Js(jQuery).`С каждого по чуть чуть знаю,суть такова есть таблица которая заполнена данными из БД при помощи `HIbernate`,и эти данные я беру при помощи `jquery` обрабатываю их и тд.В таблице у каждого стоблца 5 элемент это кнопка.Теперь Хочу по нажатию на кнопки запустить еще один скрипт который берет мои обработанные данные и вставляет их в бин и затем через метод я обновлю это значение в БД.Я незнаю как сделать чтоб при нажатии на кнопку запустить скрипт ,мне ненадо предлогать `js` функции .`click`.Надо сделать на Jave но как внутри метода java запускать скрипт???Ребята буду благодарен за все за любые  подсказки направления ,очень нужна помощь...Незнаю что делать ...СПасибо

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Вам поможет схема SPA. Из java можно вызвать javascript например в виде callback-a, т.е. все таки отловить click с помощью js передать управление java с помощью Ajax, исполнить логику java кода и вернуть данные обратно скрипту где выполнить callback с нужным js.

Comment: А можете мне попобдробнее сказать  передать управление java с помощью Ajax вот про это где мне почитать?)

Comment: Если используете jQuery то про Ajax хорошо написано в части 3 книги 
Адам Фримен "jQuery для профессионалов" 2013

Comment: Спасибо обезательно посматрю !